# page coordinate vs TeX coordinate

Tags: coordinates

I am reading the synctex source code, now I found he comment mentioned two type of coordinates, page coordinates and TeX coordinates. anyone know about the two type of coordinate system? The docs only mention that page coordinate `The origin is at the top left corner of the page.`